# How to combine the last 2 dimensions of Numpy Array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I already saw [How to combine dimensions in numpy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36370956/how-to-combine-dimensions-in-numpy-array)

And tried that, but when I tried

```
imgs.reshape(img.shape[:-2]+(-1))
```

which I assumed would be the logical extension, I get an error:

```
can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple
```

I was going to comment on the accepted answer from the linked question and ask them for help directly instead of creating a new thread for this but I don't have the required reputation to comment.

Edit:
For example, I have an input array that is of shape `(x,y,8,8)` where x and y can change depending on the image that is fed into the function. I want to make it into an array of shape `(x,y,64)`. The 64 in this case never changes.

Comment: provide sample data and expected output

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must add a comma for it to be recognized as a tuple. Try

```
imgs.reshape(img.shape[:-2] + (-1,))
```

Or, use unpacking:

```
imgs.reshape((*img.shape[:-2], -1))
```

Comment: I had also tried your first suggestion and it was giving me back (x,y,9) instead of (x,y,64) for some reason. Your second suggestion worked though, thank you!